# Monitoring instances in Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS) using Python

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, autoscaling, azure-monitoring, azure-autoscaling-block

I want to monitor and get information regarding the different instances in an Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set (VMSS).

I used the command (Python):

vmss = compute_client.virtual_machine_scale_sets.list(resource_group, scale_set_name)

But I am not able to get the result I am expecting.

Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: well, use monitoring solutions?

Comment: If you do not mind using 3rd party products, look into CloudMonix @ https://www.cloudmonix.com -- it fully supports VMSS, any performance counters, instance healing and scaling, and more... HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the VMs information, please use the following code.

```
subscription_id = 'subscription Id'
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id=CLIENT, secret=KEY, tenant=TENANT_ID)
client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
vmss = client.virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.list("resourcegroup Name","VMSS name")
for item in vmss:  
    print("id:",item.id)
    print("name",item.name)
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but this gives me only the names of the instances that are actually running before or after a scale-in or scale-out has occured. But I want to get the information regarding those instances. Like IP address, instance state (running or stopped) etc. So, I want to monitor those instances that are running currently running in the VMSS. I checked the following link, but was not able to get the required output:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2015_06_15.operations.virtualmachinescalesetvmsoperations?view=azure-python#list

Comment: Is there any specific documentation, which I can use to get info regarding the instances like the .id and .name u have used? Because .ip or.discinfo doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get the ip and powerstate.

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
vmss = compute_client.virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.list(resource_group_name="", vmss="")
for item in vmss:
    print("name: ", item.name)
    ni_reference = item.network_profile.network_interfaces[0].id
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    nic = resource_client.resources.get_by_id(
        ni_reference,
        api_version='2017-12-01')
    ip_reference = nic.properties['ipConfigurations'][0]['properties']
    print("ip info: ", ip_reference)

    instance_view = compute_client.virtual_machine_scale_set_vms.get_instance_view(resource_group_name="", vmss="", instance_id=item.instance_id)
    print(instance_view.statuses[1].code)
```

result:

```
name:  yangtestvmss_1
ip info:  {'provisioningState': 'Succeeded', 'privateIPAddress': '10.0.0.5', 'privateIPAllocationMethod': 'Dynamic', 'subnet': {'id': '/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/resourceGroups/yangtestvmss/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/yangtestvmssVnet/subnets/default'}, 'primary': True, 'privateIPAddressVersion': 'IPv4', 'isInUseWithService': False}
PowerState/running
name:  yangtestvmss_3
ip info:  {'provisioningState': 'Succeeded', 'privateIPAddress': '10.0.0.7', 'privateIPAllocationMethod': 'Dynamic', 'subnet': {'id': '/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/resourceGroups/yangtestvmss/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/yangtestvmssVnet/subnets/default'}, 'primary': True, 'privateIPAddressVersion': 'IPv4', 'isInUseWithService': False}
PowerState/running
```

Comment: and how can i get the publlic ip of instance in vmss ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool tool that a guy from Microsoft has been build for monitoring VMSS
see this link [VMSS Dashboard](https://github.com/gbowerman/vmssdashboard)

The mentioned tool helps you to see the status of VMs in the scale set: you can see the update domain and fault domain grouping of VMs. It lets you start or deallocate a VM. The code is for more than two years ago.

Comment: Could you please summarize here the contents of the link?

Comment: The mentioned tool helps you to see the status of VMs in the scale set, you can see the update domain and fault domain grouping of VMs. It let you start or deallocate a VM. The code is for more than two years ago.